# Storing & fetching the cached data from JSON webservice in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios4, core-data, plist

I am looking to create a **Cache Manager class for News** which can be used in other iPhone projects also. My cache manager would support caching of JSON data i.e Text & Image & storing it locally in iPhone. The primary idea behind this is to enable the application access the cached data resulting in reducing the network activity.

I am thinking to have this thing implement in the following ways :

1. Sqlite Database i.e fetching all the data & storing
2. Adding this data to some .plist file
3. Core-Data

**I tried with this code for second solution:**

```
NSString *plistPath = [self Return_PlistPathCreation]; // Method to creat the JSON file locaally under Documents

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:newsArray forKey:@"homenews"]; //newsArray is the array containing objects parsed from the JSON webservice 
     NSLog(@"JSON representation for dictionary is %@",[dict JSONRepresentation]); //it prints perfectly

    [[dict JSONRepresentation] writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil]; //Not not able to write it within the file
```

What wrong with above code?

So, which one would the better way for storing the cached data looking towards the performance & responsiveness of the application? Though I am open to new ideas, if there are any other ways other than above?

Answer (score 1):

The very best, more capable and easiest to implement solution is the third one, Core-Data. If you want to get the most versatile app in terms of future new functions development, my advice  i to design your app based in this architectural paradigm:

1. Define a data base and Core-Data access with managed objects for the content you are going to download. This database is not only the cache but the main data of your app.
2. Build your app bassed in that core-data data base and access to the data, in all your viewControllers that you can, via UIFetchedResultsController. Implement the easy refresh of views based in fetchedViewController delegate methods.
3. Build background functions, independent of the rest of the app, that download the contents from the Internet and stores them in Core-Data. The views will refresh automatically without more effort from you as developer.

I hope this is useful for u

Comment: & How's about the images , How do I write/store them in Core Data ?

Comment: I don't save images in core data but in the file system. In core data I only have the reference to the file. If you develop with discipline and every time you remove a core-data object pointing to a image file you delete that file, there is not any complicated work to do. BTW, I don't use the original names of files in cache directory to avoid duplicate names. The final file name is a string in core data object.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell you something, don't use the default Cache Directory that iOS offers for your app. You are going to manage the files folder, so use Documents folder. Cache folder is for non permanent files and you need them to be there as far as core data objets point to them.

Comment: hey you got to see any good tutoria for Core data or what you are looking to explain me.Since I am new to Core data . Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building this yourself, because its a very complicated problem, why not just use something like RestKit?

Answer (score 0):

As i have learned from Standford Uni. CS193p video lectures you should almost never use SQLite in your applications. Core Data is a little compicated but if your data has a complicated graph will be beter. I think using property list(plist) will be better:)

Note: I used NSUserDefaults to save JSON data and use in different classes later, there are caching methods too in [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) link.

Comment: and also there are a lot of libraries, as @wattson12 has mentioned, like RestKit